# How can I get Git to display differences in an editor for uncommitted changes?

Tags: git

I cloned a Git repository and would like to see the changes from the files in my directory compared against HEAD in my editor (vi). I normally use difftool for this job but it only seems to accept commits, not working files. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Got it - if there are no changes in the file then difftool just exits. Otherwise, it pops up the diff tool.